# Is space is not normal?

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

**Question**: let $X=\mathbb{R}$ with topology generated by open intervals of the form $(a,b)$and sets of the form $\mathbb{Q}∩(a,b)$ then $X$ is not normal space.

**My attempt**: I know if for each pair of disjoint closed sets $A$ and $B$, if there exists open sets $U$ and $V$ such that, $A⊆U$ , $B⊆V$ and $U∩V≠∅$ then space will be normal and complements of sets in topology are closed sets in space. But, however I am unable to find such disjoint pair of closed sets and unable to prove if such pair exists then, how to show they are not separate. I am beginner in topology, please help me..:-(

Comment: Please write a better title

Comment: @ZacharySelk ,Sir suggest me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try separating the closed set $\mathbb{P} = \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$
from the closed set $\{0\}$.

Comment: Sir, how $\{0\}$ is closed set in this topology sir? Because closed sets are complement of open sets and so $\{0\}$ complement of open set (-∞,0) ∪ (0,+∞) is am I correct sir?

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi indeed, and the rationals are open so their complement closed.

Comment: Thank u  Sir then, could you please help me to prove there exists $x∈\mathbb{R\Q}$ such that every neighborhood of $x$ has non-empty intersection with neighborhood of $0$ so that, it will show we can't separate them.

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi every separate $x \in \mathbb{P}$ can be separated from $0$ but the whole of $\mathbb{P}$ cannot. $X$ is Hausdorff but not regular.